# Distance betwween LineString and Point

Tags: python, distance, shapely

I have the following StringLine

```
Line =  [(-58.39323087479187, -34.64522852285068), (-58.39493519860744, -34.64593911202303), (-58.39540370387294, -34.64612018963881), (-58.39577715270643, -34.64624297063709), (-58.3961720086682, -34.64636735300267), (-58.39657393244798, -34.64649079664271), (-58.39686900560828, -34.64658786576401), (-58.39768408267521, -34.64688376919202), (-58.39804117638568, -34.64699057960223), (-58.39811749931905, -34.64700849164973), (-58.39828903137601, -34.64704378391358), (-58.39848415993365, -34.64708122410398), (-58.3986547387477, -34.64709449060737), (-58.3988514934597, -34.64709955836587), (-58.39897325079004, -34.6471023653607), (-58.39913887311855, -34.64708744614302), (-58.40078230339798, -34.64694668280777), (-58.4011366548087, -34.64692373544752), (-58.40140137506319, -34.64690660901691), (-58.40169294994597, -34.64689298223946), (-58.40188791399491, -34.64691373562576), (-58.40216794959328, -34.64695369573664), (-58.41441599275006, -34.64898345419851), (-58.41468645364731, -34.64902341675737), (-58.41491789917437, -34.6490522244158), (-58.41504783372419, -34.64906712767555), (-58.41517069354625, -34.64908171429391), (-58.41533660567228, -34.64909137548982), (-58.41610344894117, -34.64910924442286), (-58.41663883920926, -34.64911070715178), (-58.41691994816962, -34.64910623905278), (-58.41712925394172, -34.64908282123896), (-58.41735140092969, -34.64905175937751), (-58.4175040105956, -34.64901464682342), (-58.41778163827102, -34.64893890857992), (-58.41810776345819, -34.64882463807892), (-58.42014859446244, -34.64801074189261), (-58.42109129459963, -34.64768468167974), (-58.42150738131538, -34.64755870865789), (-58.42342555778116, -34.64704856595483), (-58.42380036444368, -34.64696522849173), (-58.42402399498763, -34.64692538456899), (-58.42422994553617, -34.64689682578112), (-58.42442882836995, -34.64688048716456), (-58.42466544132492, -34.64686749516407), (-58.42492895224804, -34.64686969903472), (-58.42519118859626, -34.64689581060387), (-58.42548633816839, -34.64693076251233), (-58.42574834123136, -34.64696690278817), (-58.42600734692162, -34.64703299983701), (-58.42633487929256, -34.64713342399471), (-58.42672363380665, -34.6472903832091), (-58.42701863504796, -34.64744017525714), (-58.42735477118806, -34.64764714102999), (-58.42758954729708, -34.64780944247776), (-58.42780426987807, -34.64798874926387), (-58.42805931284784, -34.64825160891823), (-58.42826384085686, -34.64851328718624), (-58.42836837245316, -34.64865441916345), (-58.42849097552769, -34.64886100909527), (-58.42863862000018, -34.64921981114054), (-58.43039902344795, -34.65411150588781), (-58.43058099211167, -34.65454759092934), (-58.43074440690579, -34.65487960245804), (-58.43091147516467, -34.65519055733962), (-58.43112803380347, -34.65554914847827), (-58.43260609566938, -34.65801519415205), (-58.43278567440816, -34.65827265019357), (-58.43296016110701, -34.65845540315134), (-58.43315011877778, -34.65865061801186), (-58.43335842356506, -34.65885169235345), (-58.43349821535271, -34.65894935913921), (-58.43369231539262, -34.65907745659961), (-58.43391244522258, -34.65921105679707), (-58.4342196854351, -34.65939138210857), (-58.43446159367213, -34.65950262175289), (-58.4354319679709, -34.65989668701516), (-58.44002778106239, -34.66183363815986), (-58.44218397209216, -34.66275027310008), (-58.46163757545956, -34.67090968101208), (-58.46246050330255, -34.67120817614321), (-58.46280547898094, -34.67132107658005), (-58.46307488578911, -34.67139608443851), (-58.46332241010779, -34.67144991252323), (-58.46353300409209, -34.67149541798045), (-58.46859653017688, -34.67249959570204), (-58.46908781436287, -34.67259411624501), (-58.46938034898276, -34.67267684368898), (-58.46981999535013, -34.67282189408634), (-58.47017709131737, -34.67296547046871), (-58.47422872212128, -34.67473003403723), (-58.47458907678709, -34.67490463353656), (-58.47485536868304, -34.67507001487545), (-58.47511721636123, -34.67527809815956), (-58.47561611823835, -34.67573966172805), (-58.47637678148585, -34.67650147966764), (-58.4772898411353, -34.677473083393), (-58.47756878106423, -34.67779366716631), (-58.47927838887487, -34.68008637250686), (-58.4796189824651, -34.68046368453628), (-58.4797836819284, -34.68061589623475), (-58.47997298162954, -34.68077149644261), (-58.48013854950542, -34.68087214089938), (-58.48033951807771, -34.68099482470753), (-58.48077178430249, -34.68117907983302), (-58.4809809942354, -34.68125468946911), (-58.48151812211091, -34.68141121492266), (-58.49074865351113, -34.68364996209967), (-58.49280644305118, -34.68416717487745), (-58.49323181266317, -34.68430677581161), (-58.4939040130434, -34.68450404480966), (-58.494446444632, -34.68469758388901), (-58.50679022633284, -34.68987115611775), (-58.50863040256832, -34.6906581855909), (-58.51021336002367, -34.69130911057548), (-58.51092048468821, -34.69162906732615), (-58.51128148474532, -34.69180116103016), (-58.51164513166684, -34.69197626961216), (-58.51190552938787, -34.6921423269721), (-58.51223224913973, -34.6923465503359), (-58.51266317587315, -34.69263696928233), (-58.51283797439013, -34.69275574911642), (-58.51343928772994, -34.69323891435921), (-58.51613617076313, -34.69565149779803), (-58.51639524277449, -34.6959621229764), (-58.51657880735801, -34.69623621532357), (-58.51668736518741, -34.69648714304233), (-58.51677990482248, -34.69677220564932), (-58.51681912473175, -34.69694815217243), (-58.51683540541565, -34.69728978685934), (-58.51682586767205, -34.69757721116119), (-58.51679226699013, -34.697818097686), (-58.51670205772855, -34.69812198637412), (-58.51657448656194, -34.69837726193614), (-58.51643210417134, -34.69861385564264), (-58.51621815101113, -34.69887195886386), (-58.5160233966457, -34.69905049204797), (-58.51546229204164, -34.69948099921363), (-58.51164101129704, -34.70237114559549)]
```

And this point:

```
Point = (-58.503015,-34.704488)
```

In another hand I have this code:

```
    from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point, LinearRing

p = Point(Punto)
linea=LineString(line)
line1 = list(linea.coords)
print(linea.project(p))

np = linea.interpolate(linea.project(p))
a = p.distance(linea)
print(np)
print(a)
```

I get that the point that makes up the line closest to the point of comparison is:(-58.51164101129704, -34.70237114559549)
And the distance (0.008881956060), but I need the distance between the point and the line that joining the points.

**See attached image to understand the context.**

Let's suppose that the red circles are the points that form the LineString and the black point is the one to which I must measure the distance.

As you can see in the image, it is between two points but I need to measure against the line that I painted with green colour, since it is the closest to the black point.

[See attached image to understand the context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyAPs.png)

Comment: Do you consider than the line between 2 points (in your Line) is straight ?

Comment: In this case the line are not straight, but for this time maybe we need to consider then the line is straight. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Im thinking about considering the 2 closest points from your original points. You would have `A` as your original points, and `B, C` as the 2 closest points on the line. Make a triangle `ABC`, and calculate the height of triangle `ABC` from `A` to base `BC`. This should be the shortest, except for an edge case, let me recap.

```
shortest_dist = height_of_triangle(top, base)
if shortest_dist > distance_between_top_and_either_points:
    shortest_dist = distance_between_top_and_closest_point
```

If you don't get my logic behind this, just tell. :)